# R can't find a package on a shared drive

Tags: r

I have a shared drive with several versions of R. The R script gets executed by a SQL Server agent job every 5 minutes.

It recently started throwing the following error.

[image]

This has worked fine for the past year.

Furthermore, the data.table package is installed on the shared drive.

[image]

I am running data.table_1.9.6 on an R instance installed on the shared drive ( R 3.6.0 )

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Was anything updated (even if it doesn't seem to be related) on the server? My guess is that something changed in the server's environment (network shares, mapping, user-permissions, etc). I think you should expand your search _well_ outside of the [tag:r] tag, to include however the system is being administered. (I'm not saying that R is not useful, but it is only going to be able to give you the _symptoms_ here and not the underlying problem.)

Comment: Check the `.libPaths()` to see what folders R is looking in for packages. (Assuming the packages you **can** load like `lubridate` are in the same folder, It is a bit suspicious that the one package giving you problems is the one that was last updated today... maybe check the permissions for the `data.table` folder and make sure it is the same as the others...)

Comment: I removed SQL server as it's clear that is not part of the issue

Comment: @DaleK it's "clear" except the script is being run by SQL Server, and if something in its configuration or view of the world changed, then it is "clearly" a symptom. I don't use R through SQL Server, but I cannot see how the server is completely unrelated to services that no longer run through it.

Comment: It's a missing package therefore nothing to do with SQL server

Comment: The symptom is that a package cannot be found. The cause is unlikely that R just changed one day, something else has happened. Until the OP can identify what has happened recently (e.g., upgraded SQL Server, changed network-share password, moved R to another directory, could be many things) that can cause this symptom, it is just as possible that the server is part of the "what changed" discussion.

Comment: So ATMA, you've been silent. What has changed in and around the R instance and SQL Server?